# Group by one column when other column differs

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I am kinda stuck with a query that should increase dataquality of subscribers. I want to get all subscribers that have the same email-adress while they have different customer-numbers.

Here is an example of the test dataset that I set up.

[image]

The temporary table which probably ends up being a subquery would look similar to this:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

Probably with a `having` clause of `CustomerCount > 1` you would then ignore those that have a customercount of 1. For all these subscribers I would like to get every column in the original dataset (it hs more column than displayed here).

This would look like:

[image]

**How do I write a query or multiple queries for this?**

---

---

---

*Side Question:
Another question just to get a better understanding of the group by:*

```
SELECT Count(Email) as CustomerCount, Email
FROM [SubscriberData]
GROUP BY Email, CustomberNumber
```

Why does this query returns the customerCount of 1 for Email f@salesforce.com instead of 2?

My understanding would be it is 1 because the last customer has f@salesforce.com while it would have been 2 before when it passed customer 4.

---

---

---

For those who want to test the test-dataset:

```
subscriberKey;customerNumber;email
1;1;a@salesforce.com
2;1;a@salesforce.com
3;1;b@salesforce.com
4;2;c@salesforce.com
5;2;d@salesforce.com
6;3;b@salesforce.com
7;3;d@salesforce.com
8;4;e@salesforce.com
9;4;e@salesforce.com
10;4;f@salesforce.com
11;4;f@salesforce.com
12;5;f@salesforce.com
13;6;f@salesforce.com
14;7;f@salesforce.com
```

Comment: It would be nice if the person that downvoted the question leaves atleast a description why. The only thing that I know of would be moving this towards dba.stackexchange.com but since marketing cloud is only able to perform a subset of all available functions of t-sql i believe that it is better suited inside this forum, because otherwise you will most likely get answers from dba.stackexchange that will not work on the marketing-cloud plattform.

Comment: Your side question -- it returns multiple rows for `f@salesforce.com` because you're also grouping by `CustomerNumber`.  If you include `CustomerNumber` you can see why you get that count: https://i.imgur.com/UBsaYoz.png

Comment: Why isn't `a@salesforce.com` included in your desired output table?

Comment: I still am not quite getting exactly what you are looking for in final output. What is the main goal of this? Get number of records that have same email address but not same customernumber?

Comment: The main goal is to detect bad quality. If there is are two or more customers that share the same email, one of them is most likely to be obsolete. That’s why we wanna check these records

Comment: @AdamSpriggs a@salesforce.com is not included because both subscriber share the same customernumber and are not on any other customernumber. Therefore the record should not be printed out - or a different query should only select those. But you need the middle subquery for it to get how many different customers share that email adress. It is like you want both but you need to separate the result afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how many Subscribers have the same email address, you can do this with sub queries

```
SELECT c.subscriberKey
      ,c.customerNumber
      ,c.email
      ,c.CustomerCount
FROM (
    SELECT a.subscriberKey
          ,a.customerNumber
          ,a.email
          ,(
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM [SubscriberData] AS b
            WHERE a.email = b.email
          ) AS CustomerCount
    FROM [SubscriberData] AS a
) AS c
WHERE c.CustomerCount> 1
```

[image]